# Angular 8. Load images from folder lazy loaded modules

Tags: angular, image, angular8

I am trying to load images from the lazy module folder in Angular 8.
Previously this was done in Angular 6 and it worked correctly.
Now, I have updated the application to Angular 8 and I cannot load the images.
The structure of the project is as follows:

```
app/
    modules/
        module_1/
            assets/
                images/
                    image_module_1.png
            module_1.component.ts
            module_1.module.ts
        module_2/
            assets/
                images/
                    image_module_2.png
            module_2.component.ts
            module_2.module.ts
    app.module.ts
```

I would like to load the image_module_1.png from the component of that module (module_1.component.ts).

Comment: Why dont you put everything into asset folder ?

Comment: I'm developing a modular application with lazy modules and I would like to avoid loading assets from modules that are not going to run

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the solution. You have to edit the angular.json file and add the corresponding configuration in assets. In my case, we must add this:

```
{ "glob": "**/assets/**", "input": "src/", "output": "/assets/" }
```

It will include all the files inside the assets folder that is from the path src/ and will add them in the path /assets/ when building.

Comment: Is the asset folder lazy loaded? let say I have 10k images in asset folder, how does my website loads? As in this case I will definitely be needing lazy loading.